# Make custom request metrics at Spring Webflux

Tags: prometheus, spring-webflux, spring-micrometer

I have to make next metrics for all http requests of Spring Webflux app:

- time from receiving a request to being laid to the request pool
- waiting time for processing in the pool request
- processing time (untill the response sending)

I found class `MetricsWebFilter` that creates micrometer time metric of total request duration. But what with inner metrics? How can I get time of putting request to request pool? Or getting request for processing from the pool? I understand, that this timestamps can be get by aspect before and after hooks for certain method. But what method and classes? Need I make some context for saving information about previous timestamp (may be map with key as request id)?

Help please with such task, please